# Not getting recent value from my custom table in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, cache

I am showing customer available customer credit limit and used customer credit limit in my custom module. When I run the `php bin/magento cache:clean` it's working and showing correct value. When I didn't run the above command it's showing old values, the recent values are not showing.

Could you please suggest me how to resolve this?

for this I have written below code.

**Block/CreditLimit.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;


class Creditlimit extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{


    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $_salesOrder;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Namespace\Model\CreditlimitusedlogFactory
     */
    protected  $_creditlimitusedLogFactory;


    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        \Vendor\Namespace\Model\CreditlimitusedlogFactory $creditlimitusedlogFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_creditlimitusedLogFactory = $creditlimitusedlogFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;

    }

    /**
     * Returns available credit limit used of customer
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAvailableCreditLimit() {

        $creditLimits = 0;

        $customerSession = $this->_customerSession->create();
        $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $customAttributes = $customer->getCustomAttributes();

        foreach($customAttributes as $k => $v){
            if($v->getAttributeCode() == 'credit_limit'){
                $creditLimits = $v->getValue();
            }
        }

        if($creditLimits > 0){
            $creditLimit = $creditLimits;
        }else{
            $creditLimit = 0;
        }

       $customer_credit_limit = number_format($creditLimit, 2, '.', '');
        return $customer_credit_limit;
    }

    /**
     * Returns Used Credit Limit amout of Customer
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsedCreditLimit(){

        $order_total = 0;

        $customerSession = $this->_customerSession->create();
        $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $creditlimit = $this->_creditlimitusedLogFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId));

        foreach ($creditlimit as $_creditlimit) {
            $order_grand_total = $_creditlimit->getData('order_grand_total');
            $invoiced_grand_total = $_creditlimit->getData('invoiced_grand_total');
            $cal_total = $order_grand_total - $invoiced_grand_total;

            if($cal_total > 0){
                $order_total = $order_total + $cal_total;
            }
        }

        $customer_used_credit_limit = number_format($order_total, 2, '.', '');

        return $customer_used_credit_limit;

    }


}
```

**view/frontend/layout/creditlimit_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Credit Limit</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Creditlimit" name="creditlimit" template="Vendor_Namespace::Creditlimit.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/templates/Creditlimit.phtml**

```
<?php /** @var $block Vendor\Namespace\Block\Creditlimit */?>
<br/>
<?php

$command = 'php bin/magento cache:clean';
shell_exec($command);

?>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Available Credit Limit: $</span><?php echo $block->getAvailableCreditLimit(); ?>
<br/>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Used Credit Limit: $</span><?php echo $block->getUsedCreditLimit(); ?>
```

Even though I have written the `php bin/magento cache:clean` command in `.phtml` file. But No luck.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your layout code

```
<block class="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Creditlimit" name="creditlimit" template="Vendor_Namespace::Creditlimit.phtml" />
```

to

```
<block class="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Creditlimit" name="creditlimit" template="Vendor_Namespace::Creditlimit.phtml" cacheable="false" />
```

I have added **cacheable="false"** in above code